# Forward Pass in Caffe NN in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, caffe, pycaffe

I have a Caffe neural network and I want to do forward pass (using the GPU) in the network without blocking the main thread. I am using python, I tried using threading and multiprocessing. They are using the CPU even though I am asking it to use the GPU. Here's my code:

```
class ThreadingWorker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ThreadingWorker,self).__init__()
        param = config()
        self.model = param.model
        self.net = caffe.Net(self.model.deployFile, self.model.caffemodel, caffe.TEST)

    def run(self):
        input_data = np.random.rand(1,4,self.model.width,self.model.height)
        start = time()
        self.net.forward(data=input_data)
        print 'Success, took %f seconds' % (time()-start)      

class MultProcessingWorker(mp.Process):
    def run(self):
        param = config()
        self.model = param.model
        self.net = caffe.Net(self.model.deployFile, self.model.caffemodel, caffe.TEST)
        input_data = np.random.rand(1,4,self.model.width,self.model.height)
        start = time()
        self.net.forward(data=input_data)
        print 'Success, took %f seconds' % (time()-start)      

class NormalWorker(object):
    '''Using the main thread, no parallelization is being used here'''
    def __init__(self):
        param = config()
        self.model = param.model
        self.net = caffe.Net(self.model.deployFile, self.model.caffemodel, caffe.TEST)

    def run(self):
        input_data = np.random.rand(1,4,self.model.width,self.model.height)
        start = time()
        self.net.forward(data=input_data)
        print 'Success, took %f seconds' % (time()-start)   

p = NormalWorker()
p.run()

>> Success, took 0.34 seconds

thread = ThreadingWorker()
thread.start()   

>> Success, took 3.54 seconds

p = MultProcessingWorker()
p.start()

>> Success, took 3.45 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar Problem.

using

```
caffe.set_mode_gpu()
```

in the child thread itself solved it.

So try:

```
class MultProcessingWorker(mp.Process):
    def run(self):

        caffe.set_mode_gpu() # <---  should fix the problem

        param = config()
        self.model = param.model
        self.net = caffe.Net(self.model.deployFile, self.model.caffemodel, caffe.TEST)
        input_data = np.random.rand(1,4,self.model.width,self.model.height)
        start = time()
        self.net.forward(data=input_data)
        print 'Success, took %f seconds' % (time()-start)
```